# Evitar reenviar correo al recargar la pagina

Tags: php, javascript, phpmailer, navigation

Una pregunta habría alguna forma de evitar el reenvió del email (estoy utilizando la librería PHPMailer) al recargar la pagina sin necesidad de usar un botón, puesto que estoy desarrollando un sistema de notificaciones, pero tengo un problema que como las notificaciones se mantienen en la pagina hasta que el usuarios las vea y cambie, entonces cuando el usuario recarga o vuelve a ingresar a la pagina y las notificación están todavía hay me vuelve a enviar el email.

He intentado incrementar una variable cada vez que se envié el correo, y asi cuando la variable sea mayor a 1 no me envié mas correos, pero cuando se recarga la pagina no me guarda el valor de la variable incrementada.

Agradezco sus respuestas.

Este es código:

```
<?php 

$timeActual= time(); 
$hoy = date('Y-m-d');
$dia3 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 day'));

foreach($documentos as $user){

$fechaDB = $user->fecha_fin;

if ($fechaDB <> "0000-00-00") {

    if( $fechaDB <= $hoy ) {

?> 

<div class="container col-md-offset-0">
  <div  class="alert alert-info  alert-dismissible col-lg-6">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-
 hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i> Alerta!</h4>
    <?php echo "<b>CLIENTE: </b>".$user->nombre;?>
    <br><b>NOTIFICACION: </b>Contrato terminado <?php  echo " - "."<b>FECHA 
FIN: </b>".$user->fecha_fin; ?>
  </div>
</div>

<?php

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
 )
);
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';//Modificar
 $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';//Modificar
 $mail->Port = '587';//Modificar
 $mail->Username = 'AplicativoSFMC@gmail.com'; //Modificar
 $mail->Password = 'Aplicativomc'; //Modificar

 $mail->setFrom('AplicativoSFMC@gmail.com', 'Sistema control de 
 facturación');//Modificar

 $mail->addAddress('eduardbaker98@hotmail.com', ' Sr. Omar Rincon');//
 $mail->addAddress('eduard_rr@hotmail.com', ' Sr. Eduardo 
 Ramirez');//Modificar
 $mail->IsHTML(true);

 $html='


 <html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Mensaje de prueba</h1>
  <p>Hola mundo XD</p>
  <img 
 src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/3140696879/1429203807/1500x500" 
 width="300" height="100">

 </body>
 </html>


';
$mail->Subject = 'Notificación';//Modificar
$mail->Body = $html; //Modificar



$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$intentos=0; 

if($intentos == 0){
$intentos++;
$mail->send();
 echo 'Enviado';
   return true;
 } else {  
echo 'Error';
return false;

}

 }else if ($fechaDB == $dia3){

 ...
 ?>
```

**EDICION SOLUCION**

Cree una tabla llamada notificaciones con los campos `ID,  VALOR, ID_DOCUMENTOS`  como las notificaciones son según la fecha del la tabla NOTIFICACIONES  hice la siguiente consulta

```
$sql = "SELECT id, valor, id_documentos from notificacion WHERE id = 
id and id_documentos = '$user->id'";
```

Esta consulta lo que hace es traerme los datos de la tabla NOTIFICACIONES según el id_documentos, y por ultimo la condición

```
if($row["valor"] == 0){
$mail->send();

$sql = "INSERT INTO notificacion (valor, alerta, id_documentos) VALUES 
(1,$user->id')";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

}else{

}
```

la cual me mira si la alerta que esta asignada a ese documento tiene el campo valor en 0... si es así  me envía el email y realiza el insert con el campo enviado en 1, entonces cuando vuelvo a recargar la pagina, como el campo esta en 1 no me vuelve a enviar.

Comment: Yo tuve un problema bastante parecido, lo solucione añadiendo a la base de datos un campo booleano que me decia si el mail habia sido enviado.
Por otro lado deja tu codigo y lo que has intentado para poder servirte de mas ayuda. Pasate por el [tour] y por [ask] y luego [edit] la pregunta

Comment: Ya publique el código!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es el siguiente, cuando recargas la pagina `$intentos=0;` vuelve a definirse como 0 de esta forma siempre va a entrar en el if. Podrias usar variables de sesion.

Asi se definen:

```
<?php
    //Inicias la sesion
    session_start();
    //Compruebas si se ha definido la variable

    if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
        $_SESSION['count'] = 0; // si no lo esta la dejas a 0
    } else {
        $_SESSION['count']++; // si ya existe sumas uno
    }
?>


Si lo aplicamos a tu codigo deberia quedarse algo asi:
//Inicias la sesion
session_start();
//Compruebas si se ha definido la variable
if (!isset($_SESSION['enviado']) || $_SESSION['enviado'] == false) {
  $_SESSION['enviado'] = true; // si no lo esta la dejas a 0
  $mail->send();
  echo 'Enviado';
  return true;
} else {
  echo 'Error';
  return false;
}
```

Lo he cambiado a una variable booleana porque no necesitas saber cuantas veces se ha enviado, sino si ya ha sido enviado.

#### EDICION

Viendo que tienes que crear una nueva tabla en la base de datos te indico la forma en la que yo lo haría.

<sub>Nota: Desconozco la estructura de tu base de datos por lo que esta solución la tendras que adaptar</sub>

Digamos que tienes una tabla de usuarios (a los cuales le envias la notificación).

Esta tabla podria ser asi:

```
USUID   USUNOMBRE   USUAPELLIDO USUAPELLIDO2
```

Luego otra tabla de notificaciones, con la id de la notificacion y su mensaje.

Algo asi:

```
NOTIID  NOTIDESC
```

Por ultimo creas una tabla de Emails, esta podría tener una fecha de envio y las id de el usuario y de las notificaciones (si los usuarios tienen mas de un email tambien podrias añadir el campo email) y para asegurar un campo booleano que nos diga si se ha enviado con exito o no.

Quedaria asi:

```
EMAILID USUID   NOTIID  FECENVIO    ENVIADO
```

Eso seria la parte de la base de datos, como en el primer ejemplo explico como hacerlo con la variable de sesión ahora lo hare (sin complicarme mucho con las sql) con la base de datos.

Lo primero que deberias hacer es recoger en variables la información que necesitas, es decir, el id del usuario al que se le envia la notificación, la id de la notificación y lo mas importante y lo que a ti te interesa, si ha sido enviada.

Con una sql mas o menos asi podrias comprobar si esa notificacion ha sido enviada.

```
SELECT USUID, NOTIID, ENVIADO FROM EMAIL WHERE USUID = ? and NOTIID = ? and ENVIADO = TRUE
```

Entonces, si obtienes algun registro sera que el email ya ha sido enviado y ademas con exito, en el caso que no tengas ningun registro deberas hacer un `$mail->send();` y añadir un nuevo registro a la tabla email en el caso de que nunca hubieras intentado enviar esa email o un update en el caso de que el envio anterior fuese `FALSE`.

Por ultimo te indico como enviar el email y comprobar si el envio ha sido correcto o no:

```
//Antes de realizar este bloque de código, debes comprobar si existe una
//fila con los datos que vas ha enviar y el campo enviado en true.
//Si existe, no debe ejecutar el bloque ya que el email ya ha sido enviado.
if(!$mail->send()) { //Intenta enviar el correo
  //Si da error enviandolo
  //SQL INSERT (campo enviado false)      
} else {
  //Si se envia correctamente
  //Comprobar si tiene el campo enviado en false
  if($enviado == false){
     //SQL (campo enviado true)
  }else{
     //SQL INSERT (campo enviado true)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola amigo tu código funciona, Pero tengo un problema, yo ya tengo definida la variable session, ya que la pagina donde están las notificaciones se muestra una vez que el usuario se logea, el problema esta en que si el usuarios sale de la session y vuelve a entrar se vuelve a enviar el correo. Pienso yo porque cuando se cierra la session  y al ingresar otra vez la variable se resetea¡

Comment: @O.Eduard entonces lo que deberías hacer es añadir un campo en la tabla de usuarios en la base de datos donde ponga si el correo ha sido enviado o no.

Comment: @O.Eduard Lo has conseguido?

Comment: he estado intentando crear una tabla estado y que cuando se envié una notificación me haga un insert en la tabla, la tabla solo tiene dos campos el id que es auto_increment y un campo boolean, entonces cuando me envía la notificación me ingresa en el campo boolean un 1, pero no he podido hacer la condición para que no me siga enviando correos!

Comment: @O.Eduard pero tendras que relacionar el correo con algo, el usuario al que se le envia o la notificacion a la que corresponde o la direccion de correo a la que se envia, si no estaras creando un nuevo registro en la tabla cada vez que recarges.

Comment: Discúlpame pero no entendí muy bien la condición.

Comment: @O.Eduard Cuando haces `if(!$mail->send())` haces dos cosas, la primera intentas enviar el correo y la segunda comprueba si ese mismo correo se ha enviado correctamente, cuando usas `$mail->send()` sin condiciones no sabes si el correo se ha enviado con éxito.

Comment: SI entiendo, específicamente me refería al segundo  if  y a los  //UPDATE y //INSERT. Que es lo que editaría el campo enviado?

Comment: @O.Eduard Ok, cuando haces `mail -> send()` si este te da error, insertas en la base de datos el intento de envio, pero con el campo "enviado" en "false". Por lo tanto cuando no da error, primero compruebas si existe una fila con los mismos id, si existe y tiene el campo en false haces UPDATE y si no existe haces un INSERT pero en este caso con el campo enviado en "false". Actualizo el edit con un detalle que se me ha pasado.

Comment: Ya pude hacerlo me sirvió muchisimo tu ejemplo, lo hice un poco diferente pero me ha servido. Muchas gracias por tus respuestas.

Comment: @O.Eduard podrias aceptar la respuesta y comentarme los cambios que hiciste para añadirlos asi cuando otra persona tenga el mismo problema en el futuro tendra la pregunta con la respuesta adecuada